# React Native App crashes if signed and released. Works fine in debug mode

Tags: react-native

React Native App crashes if signed and released. Works fine in debug mode. It doesn't throw any error in the screen. It simply crashes. When I looked at cat log. no error.

I also tried build apk with --info, but no additional info while crashing. I also tried building APK by setting minifyEnabled false.

When run the app in debug mode by connecting my phone via USB, it works. 
I'm tried creating apk with --debug but I'm unable to install it my phone, it says parsing error when I try to install using app installer.

I got the following logcat errors.  What does it mean?

```
09-03 11:03:07.968 W/ActivityManager(1344):   Force finishing activity com.myapp/.MainActivity


09-03 11:03:08.012 W/BroadcastQueue(1344): Skipping deliver [background] BroadcastRecord{cb72147 u-1 android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE} to ReceiverList{7bf2161 22421 com.myapp/10100/u0 remote:b9cdcc8}: process crashing

09-03 11:03:08.035 W/ActivityManager(1344):  Dismiss app error dialog : com.myapp


09-03 11:03:13.095 I/WindowState(1344): WIN DEATH: Window{3f22c22 u0 /com.myapp.MainActivity}
```

Comment: Have you tried run you app without chrome debug mode?

Comment: @Xeijp you mean using react-native run-android --variant=release? I tried this, it not working. If I do react-native run-android --variant=debug, it works fine.

Comment: @Xeijp if an app crashes, in windows desktop OS, we can see some stacktrace in application events. Is there something like that in Android?

Comment: I think you can try to run release apk on emulator. There you can use logcat.

Comment: with the usb debugging on on your android device, you can view the logcat output with android studio or on the command line. Just filter for your application name, and it'll show the error when the app crashes.

Eg: `adb -d logcat <your package name>:<log level> *:S`

Comment: @nabn "Force Finishing Activitycom.myapp/.MainActivity." "skipping deliver background broadcastrecord android.net.conn. Connectivity _changed to receverlist com.myapp /10100/u0 remote fafb552} process crasing". Any idea what it means?

Comment: Can't tell you more from this information. Sorry.

Comment: I've found my solution about that.
The problem is the bundle name. I output the bundle js with name `index.android.jsbundle`, and I've changed the android/app/build.gradle, just as told by the comment above( unfortunately, it did not work, so caused the crash when open the release apk: cannot find the bundle..)
I solved it by changing the name back to the default 'index.android.bundle', it workd. Still, I wanna know what should i do if i just changed the bundle name like 'index.android.jsbundle' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the cause. There is module called react-native-material-design-searchbar which was causing the issue. The weird part is, if directly copy the SearchBar.js from that module and use it all works fine even in release, but if use module as direct import it's not working only in release mode. So weird. The SearchBar is good, so now I'm using directly by copying the file to my project.

Comment: I have the same problem but the cause is probably a different library. Can you explain how you manage to debug and found out the root cause ?

Comment: Hey can you please let me know how did you manage to debug that the issue was in specific package ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by uninstalling `uglifyjs` and reinstalled the latest (using `NPM`).